# creating tags in textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, tags

i want to create tags for input data.(http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/ajax-with-filter-tags-and-autocomplete.html hear they creating tags using auto complete text box, but i don't want auto complete one)

hear is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#textBox").keyup(function() {
        $("#message").val($(this).val());
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        TextBox 1 : <input type="textbox" id="textBox"></input>
        TextBox 2 : <input type="textarea" id="message"></input>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

hear it reflect data of textbox1 to textbox2.

now what i want is : if user enter any data(words) in textbox1 followed by space then that word should convert into tags in textbox2

Comment: @ MESSIAH, ok i got idea i will try now to integrate in my code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hailwood/u8zj5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `type=textarea` is *wrong*. There's no such `input` like that. You must be using `<textarea>` instead of that. Secondly, why dont you use `contentditable` attribute? It works just like a text area but can take HTML, is supported in all browsers, and you can use it on any block element! So replace your second `input` with this:

```
TextBox 2 : <div class="target" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Then, in your code,

```
$("#textBox").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
        $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag'>" + this.value + "</a>");
        this.value = "";
    }
});
```

(*Disclaimer*) I used the styles from SO's tags, like this :

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;
}
.tag {
    color: #3E6D8E;
    background-color: #E0EAF1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b3cee1;
    border-right: 1px solid #b3cee1;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 2.4;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.tag:hover {
    background-color: #c4dae9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c4dae9;
    border-right: 1px solid #c4dae9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/Wky2Z/

To add the tags to an array, have a variable called `tags` outside the `keypress` function :

```
var tags = [];
```

Then, in the `keypress`, you've got this `if` loop right? Push the new value into the array :

```
if (e.which === 32) {
    $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag'>" + this.value + "</a>");
    tags.push(this.value); //push the value in array
    this.value = "";
}
```

Then, when you need to save it to DB, just join them :

```
tags.join("");
```

Then later, when you to retrieve them from DB next time, you could wrap those with the `a` (what we did in the `keypress` function)

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/Wky2Z/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you give suggestion to keep thous generated tags inside array (actually i want to insert thous generated tags in to database under same id)

Comment: only the tag name or the whole `<a/>`?

Comment: entire generated tags in to same id (it some thing look like multiple locums data referring  same id)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textBox").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            $("#message").val($(this).val());
        }
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $("#message").val('');
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SvyG2/)

Comment: It's working same as my code. I want to get tags when any word followed by space, you can see example (see above link and in live demo text box type 'e' or 'f')